# React routing dynamic submenu URL changes but only first clicked submenu view is changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am fetching dynamic submenu from database under a menu. My problem is when I clicked a submenu it works fine and view is also changing. After that any submenu I clicked it doesn't changing it's view content which is also fetching from database, but URL is changing.

Like I have a menu called Services, and under this there are dynamic submenu fetched using API.

Service Menu

- Web Development
- Apps Development

**In App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Header />
                    <div>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/contact">
                                <Contact />
                            </Route>
                            <Route path="/about">
                                <About />
                            </Route>

                            <Route path="/service/:id">
                                <Service />
                            </Route>
                            
                            <Route path="/">
                                <Homepage />
                            </Route>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

**In Service.js page**

```
const Service = (props) =>{
   const [service, setservice] = useState([]);
   const id = props.match.params.id;
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/service/"+ id)
          .then(results => results.json())
          .then(res => {
            const service = res.data.service;
            setservice(service);
          });
      }, []);
   return (
      <div>
      {
         service.map((service, index) =>(
         <div key={index}>
           <h6 className="heading ">{service.service_name}</h6>             
         </div>
         ))
       }
       </div>
);
}
export default withRouter(Service);
```

Comment: That's because you're running your function once, you need it to make it run every time there's a new click. Inside your useEffect , try to put id as a dependency and see what happens

Comment: You say submenu, but what exactly are you referring to? What or where is a "Services" menu? I don't see any menu code in your snippets.

Comment: @DrewReese Menu code is in header file and also it doesn't have any action, only submenu under a menu have action.

Comment: the `useEffect` must have the `id` as a dependency `}, [id]);` so the fetch runs again when the id changes

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant code you've an issue with, the `Header` component and submenu components it render so that we may see why the URL is updating but submenu components are not.

Comment: Store the id in a state, then add it to the dependency array of useEffect

Comment: @Kirasiris Thanks, put id as a dependency inside useEffect solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. Can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

"That's because you're running your function once, you need it to make it run every time there's a new click. Inside your useEffect , try to put id as a dependency and see what happens"...

```js
const id = props.match.params.id
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/service/' + id)
    .then((results) => results.json())
    .then((res) => {
      const service = res.data.service
      setservice(service)
    })
}, [id])
```